# Focus 1st item of a menu in NavigationView

Tags: android, menu, items

I have a NavigationView made with items from a `menu`.
There are a lot of items in the menu, so the list is scrollable.

In my header, I have some pictures and when I press a button, it filters the items in the list by using         `navigationView.getMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.specific_item, false);`

This part is well working but I would like to focus on the first item of the menu when I press the button (Like if you were scrolling the menu to find something specific and you were at the letter "M", after pressing the button, the menu go back to the letter "A").

I know that for a listView we can use `.setSelection(0)` to perform this action, but for a menu, I don't know what to use.
Is there a similar command or a trick to perform a similar behaviour ?

Thank's for your help.

Comment: The `NavigationView` class allows you to specify a checked menu item via the `setCheckedItem` method: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/navigation/NavigationView#setcheckeditem (Assuming that you're looking for a way to set the currently selected menu item)

Comment: Thank's for your help but it doesn't work. The `setCheckedItem` highligh the 1st item but it doesn't focus the item for the user. I still have to scroll manually until I go back to the 1st item.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
```

Comment: Thank's for your help but it doesn't work. The `setCheckedItem` highligh the 1st item but it doesn't focus the item for the user. I still have to scroll manually until I go back to the 1st item.

Comment: You can select(highlight) the item by calling

onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));

Comment: Yes but it's not the behaviour requested. It's not necessary to highligh anything. I'm trying to automatically scroll to the 1st item of the menu. With `getItem(0)` the item is just selected but if the user was in the "M" letter in the list the screen doesn't move to go on the "A" letter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint for focusing an item on your `NavigationView`:

```kotlin
import com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuItemView

/*....*/
navView.post { navView.findViewById<NavigationMenuItemView>(R.id.nav_item_id).requestFocus() }
```

You can use the id from your menu to set `R.id.nav_item_id`.

Based on the way you are doing the filtering, you can find a reference to your first item in the menu.